# Trying to get a relative path

Tags: php

I'm trying to do this and having a lot of problems figuring it out. I know I'm a complete php noob, but I really need to figure it out and so I'd appreciate your help.

I'm trying to pass a "corrected" url to a widget on my website so if people click a button they will download the page they are on in pdf.

My website uses friendly urls http://www.sample.com/friendly/url/this/thing.html

What i need to do is grab the current url and change friendly to pdf and put the result into the button.

What I've come up with is #failsauce drizzled on #filetofpain in a #shitsandwich

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
$isHTTPS = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on");
$port = (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]) && ((!$isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !=          "80") || ($isHTTPS && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443")));
$port = ($port) ? ':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : '';
$url = ($isHTTPS ? 'https://' :    'http://').$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$port.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
return $url;
}

echo curPageURL();
?>
```

which results my url.

I have not even gotten to the replace the portion of the url part because I can't figure out how to get the url or break it up.  It's sad.

So like a beggar with a tin cup and rags on I plead for help :)

What I need to do is break up the url returned into pieces...

if it returns 
    "www.mysite.com/01/05/2013/9013/your-mom-wears-combat-boots/"
    i need to change it to:
    "www.mysite.com/pdf/9013/your-mom-wears-combat-boots.pdf"

(likely with http:// in front of it as well the posting mechanism here things I'm posting links and I have no reputation so it won't let me put the full http:// www mysite com in the examples)

Comment: Your error is two `echo`s next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You are using double `echo echo $current_url;` change to `echo $current_url;`

Comment: Sorry Niloy I was editing the Original Post... it is finished now.  The echo $current_url isn't the problem as much as figuring out how to break it up and change the url and form it into a statement :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` and `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get the requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried your code but it already seems to have a double `echo` line..

Anyway i would like to give you a pretty simple method i like to use:

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
         $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } 
    else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

what this function does is everytime you call `curPageURL()` you get your current page url, as it seems in the url bar. than you can work with it as you want.

i hope this solves your problem :)

## Edit:

To use this for getting the url and than changin the ending from `.html` to `.pdf` all you will need to do is:

```
$url = curPageURL(); // gets back www.sample.com/page.html
$newurl = str_replace(".html", ".pdf", $url); // changes url to www.sample.com/page.pdf
```

*this code uses the function from the top part of the answer*

## Edit 2:

If it returns you :`www.mysite.com/01/05/2013/9013/your-mom-wears-combat-boots/` 
than you will need to do:

```
$url = curPageURL(); // gets back www.sample.com/page/
$newurl = substr_replace($url, "", -1) // changes url to www.sample.com/page
$newurl .= ".pdf" // adds the .pdf to the url so you get www.sample.com/page.pdf
```

## Edit 3:

First of all - glad you use wordpress :)

now, the wordpress codex makes it easier, so much easier actually to do:
for this we need to make some changes, also change the curPageURL function.

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
         $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    } 
    else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

and i will explain: 
`$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` gives us the domain name, like `domain.com`. 

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` returns us everything after the domain, the path.
which in our case is for example: `01/03/2013/9013/page`.

 so now the `curPageURL` function returns just the domain name.

and now lets get to work about what's next:

```
 $url = curPageURL(); // gets back http://www.sample.com
 $url .= "/pdf"; // we add the /pdf to the url so it is now: http://www.sample.com/pdf
 $postid = get_the_ID(); // gives us the post ID. for example 9013
 $url .= "/" . $postid; // now we take the post ID and add it to the url: http://www.sample.com/pdf/9013
 $the_post = get_post($postid); // get the post by the ID
 $post_slug = $the_post['post_name']; // get the slug of the post 
 $url .= "/" . $post_slug; // adds the slug to the url: http://www.sample.com/pdf/9013/your_mom_wears_combat_boots
 $url .= ".pdf"; // finally add the pdf to the url so now you get: http://www.sample.com/pdf/9013/your_mom_wears_combat_boots.pdf
```

**and here it is without the comments:**

```
 $url = curPageURL(); 
 $url .= "/pdf";
 $postid = get_the_ID();
 $url .= "/" . $postid;
 $the_post = get_post($postid);
 $post_slug = $the_post['post_name'];
 $url .= "/" . $post_slug;
 $url .= ".pdf";
```

and if you want to minimize the lines:

```
 $url = curPageURL() . "/pdf/" . get_the_ID(); // url is now: www.domain.com/pdf/postid
 $the_post = get_post(get_the_ID());
 $url .= "/" . $the_post['post_name'] . ".pdf"; //url is now: www.domain.com/pdf/postid/post_slug.pdf
```

now you can `echo` the url by `echo $url;`

## Update, last Edit(4):

I have made a mistake, about getting the slug.

i used: `$the_post = get_post(get_the_ID());` and than took the slug, name: `$the_post['post_name']`

this wasn't right to do.

the best way to take the slug out is by running the code:
`$post_slug = basename(get_permalink());`

so this chagnes a little bit the way it supposd to look:

```
 $url = curPageURL() . "/pdf/" . get_the_ID(); // url is now: www.domain.com/pdf/postid
 $post_slug = basename(get_permalink()); //gets the post slug
 $url .= "/" . $post_slug . ".pdf"; //url is now: www.domain.com/pdf/postid/post_slug.pdf
```

and we can make it ever more minimized:

```
 $url = curPageURL() ."/pdf/". get_the_ID() ."/". basename(get_permalink()) .".pdf";
```

and now you can just `echo $url;`

don't forget: this function needs to be in the `page.php` or `single.php` for it to know what is the slug of the post and the id of the post. 

the line: `$url = curPageURL() ."/pdf/". get_the_ID() ."/". basename(get_permalink()) .".pdf";` needs to be in the loop: `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` or any other loop you use.

this should do the job :)

Comment: does the -1 take one portion off?  for instance /01/05/ the -1 would make it /01/?  I need the 9013 portion and the yourmomwears portion, but I need to insert pdf before that... so original URL looks like: www.blah.com/01/03/2013/9013/page/ to www.blah.com/pdf/9013/page.pdf so I guess I need to understand more what the substr_replace actually does to get there, it is unclear though how I would put the pdf in the middle of the string :(  Sorry I'm so slow, I feel like I should be picking this up faster.

Comment: i use the `substr_replace` to delete the last `/` so i change: `www.blah.com/01/03/2013/9013/page/` to `www.blah.com/01/03/2013/9013/page`and than i add the finish of the pdf, as you asked before. the thing i get know is that what you want is different and for giving you the solution you are looking for i will need to know what is common to all of your links in the site. so i will know how to do that for you. and another thing is - is that wordpress? the link sure looks like a common wordpress link :) and that way it would be easier to do !

Comment: Thank you :)  - Yes it is wordpress.  All of the URLs are like that it is the site name, date, postid, and seo friendly name.

for instance:
http: // www sample site / month / day / year / postid / your_mom_wears_combat_boots

what I need is to remove month, day, year and add PDF in that position, and then remove the last trailing / and put .pdf

so the result should look like this:

http: / / www sample site / pdf / postid / your_mom_wears_combat_boots.pdf

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate this. Wow thank you so much, I'm incredibly grateful for your time explaining each thing in detail.  I understand it completely.  You are great.  THANK YOU.

Comment: I have one question though :)  Where in wordpress would I put this? I've tried adding this to the widget and it gets the url as http://www.sample.com/pdf//.pdf  So it's not pulling the post id or the slug...

Comment: i am more than glad to help :)
you need to put this in the `single.php` file or in the `page.php` file. those are the pages files and the function i used need the simple functions of the page so it must be there

Comment: hey, i have made an update to my answer, i have noticed a mistake i made about taking the slug. sorry about that. but still, you can not put this in a widget because of the `post_id` part and the slug.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)  I'm going to try this right now. You Rock²

Comment: sure :) tell me how it went. if my answer was the one to help you i would be happy if you could mark my answer with the "V" :)